# Flutter : polylines show straight line

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, geolocation, fluttermap

Im implementing a flutter app to display polylines by [flutter google maps](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_maps) plugin, But It only shows a straight line between those two points rather than showing actual route, I'm not quite sure what needed to do.

Here my add markers function

```
void addMarker() {
latlng.add(LatLng(5.973804, 80.429838));
allMarkers.add(Marker(
  markerId: MarkerId('busLoc'),
  draggable: true,
  onTap: () {
    print('Marker Tapped');
  },
  position: LatLng(5.973804, 80.429838),
));

_polyline.add(Polyline(
  color: Colors.blue,
  visible: true,
  points: latlng,
  polylineId: PolylineId("distance"),
));
```

Here my scaffold

```
GoogleMap(
    
    polylines: _polyline,
    markers: Set.from(allMarkers),
    initialCameraPosition:
        CameraPosition(target: LatLng(widget.la, widget.l0), zoom: 14),
    mapType: MapType.normal,
  ),
```

And I'll attach screenshot below as well[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the route from point A to point B you will need to use Directions API that is available on the [`google_maps_webservice`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_webservice) flutter package, which is a service from Google Maps Platform that gives the route information

One of the route information is the [`overview_polyline`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview#Routes) that holds an encoded polyline representation of the route.

You can get the `overview_polyline` by having a function that sends request to Directions API using the `google_maps_webservice` package like this:

```
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/directions.dart' as directions;

final _directions = new directions.GoogleMapsDirections(apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY");

var overviewPolylines;

directions.DirectionsResponse dResponse = await _directions.directionsWithAddress(
     _originAddress, 
     _destinationAddress, 
);

if (dResponse.isOkay) {
  for (var r in dResponse.routes) {
    overviewPolylines = r.overviewPolyline.points
  }
}
```

Then, once you get the `overview_polyline` from Directions API using the sample code above, you will need to decode it using the `PolyUtil();` method from the [`google_maps_util`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_util) flutter package like this:

```
import 'package:google_maps_util/google_maps_util.dart';

PolyUtil myPoints = PolyUtil();
var pointArray = myPoints.decode(overviewPolylines);
```

Once decoded you can pass the `pointArray` to your `polyline` object like this:

```
_polyline.add(Polyline(
 color: Colors.blue,
  visible: true,
  points: pointArray,
  polylineId: PolylineId("distance"),
));
```

Comment: Great !! just what I was looking for, Thanks mate..!!

Answer (score 1):

it shows straight line because you have in your polyline only two points, so the expected behavior is to draw a line from one point to the other

Comment: so can you give me a hit what can I do to identify a route between these two point?

Comment: the concept of polyline is connecting the points you give it with lines. so if you wanna get the route between two points you have to use other api which is Direction Api      , this is a tutorial how to do it . just folow with it .   https://medium.com/flutter-community/drawing-route-lines-on-google-maps-between-two-locations-in-flutter-4d351733ccbe

Answer (score 0):

you have to use google direction API here is an article explains how to draw route between two points in flutter.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/drawing-route-lines-on-google-maps-between-two-locations-in-flutter-4d351733ccbe

Answer (score 0):

[image]In the flutterMap(flutter_map: ^6.0.1) in order to draw Line between two Point you should draw Polyline in  PolylineLayer like below code

here is my code

```
FlutterMap(
      mapController: _mapController,
      options: MapOptions(
        keepAlive: true,
        initialCameraFit: CameraFit.coordinates(
          coordinates:
              widget.markers?.map((e) => LatLng(e.point.latitude, e.point.longitude)).toList() ?? [widget.center!],
        ),
        initialCenter: widget.center ?? const LatLng(-37.750928, 145.024253),
        interactionOptions: InteractionOptions(
          flags: widget.interactiveFlag ?? InteractiveFlag.all,
        ),
        onPositionChanged: (position, hasGesture) {
          if (widget.onPositionChanged != null) {
            widget.onPositionChanged?.call(position);
          }
        },
      ),
      children: [
        TileLayer(
          urlTemplate: 'YOUR_URL_TILE',
        ),
        MarkerLayer(markers: widget.markers ?? []),
        PolylineLayer(
          polylines: [
            Polyline(
                points: widget.markers?.map((e) => LatLng(e.point.latitude, e.point.longitude)).toList() ?? [],
                color: getPrimaryColor,
                isDotted: true,
                strokeWidth: 3)
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )
```